# How can I get Django to send error emails on status codes above 500?

Tags: django, email, admin

I have migrated an old codebase to a new server and am now running Django 4.0.5.
I can send emails from the shell as follows:

```
from django.core.mail import mail_admins
mail_admins(subject='test', message='test')
```

But I don't receive any emails on 500 or higher errors.

My settings are:

```
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

ADMINS = [('My Name', 'me@provider.com'),]
MANAGERS = ADMINS
ADMIN_EMAIL = ['me@provider.com',]

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@provider.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'admin@provider.com'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@provider.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And i have tried adding:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

But they are still not sent.
I am using django-environ, but debug is set to false.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this?
may be the problem is this.
[https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#:~:text=To%20help%20keep,continue%20to%20read](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20help%20keep,continue%20to%20read).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I have access for less secure apps turned on. This is surely confirmed by the ability to send mail from the django shell?